# Interacting with akka receptionist outside of actor

Tags: akka, akka-typed

Is there a way to fetch some receptionist listings outside of actor. From documentation I see examples where some actor is subscribed to receptionist listing, but can I do it outside of actor facility.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the `ActorSystem`, you can call the `receptionist` method  to get an `ActorRef` for the receptionist.

Comment: I have reference to receptionist but I have to interact with receptionist from within some other actor, and I want to fetch recipient listing from some plain java class

Comment: If you have the reference for the receptionist, you just send it a `Receptionist.find` message using the ask pattern, and you'll get a `CompletionStage` with the `Receptionist.Listing` which will have a `Set` of registered `ActorRef`s.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Can you please provide some example of ask pattern to find a actor with CompletionStage. I am using Java Akka.